# guide to create "Hello world" web based application?

Tags: java

if I have let's say "Hello World" java application with normal interface, what are the steps needed (in general) to create a web interface for the application so I can run it and access it through the browser ?

```
public interface HelloWorld {
    public void init();
}

public class Hello implements HelloWorld {
    public void init() {
        // Do simple stuff
    }
}
```

I need to be able to invoke the method init() from a browser .

Answer (score 1):

You have several possibilities:

## Sockets

For masochists, but works on a JVM without any extra libraries or containers:

```
final ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);
while(true) {
    final Socket accept = serverSocket.accept();
    final OutputStream outputStream = accept.getOutputStream();
    final PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStream);
    printWriter.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    printWriter.println();
    printWriter.println("Hello, World!");
    printWriter.close();
}
```

All solutions below require a servlet container like [tomcat](/questions/tagged/tomcat) and packing your application to [war](/questions/tagged/war) file or deploying to some directory.

## Servlets

Working on low-level but with handy abstractions.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.getWriter().println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

## JSP

[jsp](/questions/tagged/jsp) is a simple technology where you can mix HTML markup and Java code. Kind of similar to [php](/questions/tagged/php). `index.jsp` file:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
Hello, world!
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

## Web frameworks

There are **tons** of web frameworks available for Java. Here: [spring-mvc](/questions/tagged/spring-mvc):

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/*")
    @ResponseBody
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }

}
```

As you can see, the more libraries/frameworks you use, the actual work is simpler. For simple "*Hello, world!*" application you don't need to perform many steps. But the more steps you follow during initial setup, the easier your programming model will be in the future.

Answer (score 0):

One of the finest tutorials for Java based technologies are **roseindia.net**.For web development in Java you can start with jsp.
Refer:  [jsp tutorial](http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/) to gain an understanding of this technology.

Comment: Roseindia should be avoided. http://balusc.blogspot.in/2008/06/what-is-it-with-roseindia.html